# How to connect multiple MVC elements/modules for the same page?

Tags: javascript, java, model-view-controller, view, model

I have multiple UI elements on the same page. Each of these elements I divided into Model/View/Controller. They act as modules and most of the functionality is independent to the rest of the page. Controllers deals with user interactions for that specific UI element. Model contains the data and Notifier to update the View if any data changes. Some user actions might require to collect the data from another Model and then I need to trigger another Models View. How can I connect those MVC elements with another MVC elements in the single page?

At the moment, I thought of couple solutions.

1. Create a big model, instead of having small models and pass it around as a dependency to each Controller. Then notify that specific view.
2. Create some kind of model to model relationship between two elements, so that state change on one model would affect the other model (Through dependencies, notifications).
3. Create Controller to Controller relationship between two elements. Maybe something like explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7a79cx3UaY&t=678

I would like to avoid big models and somehow retain independent modules. I am not sure how you can connect multiple MVCs in that matter.

Comment: Is this a Java or a Javascript question? How are the UI elements coded? Instinctively, I'd do something with events/notifications, but I'm not confident enough about that to state it as an answer :-)

Comment: I am more interested in general answer rather than specific language. I am trying to apply MVC pattern to the client-side application. I code with Javascript and I use it as Single Page Application. After sorting the routing I have a complex page consisting of multiple elements. Each of them has models and controllers attached to them.  I instantiate through the Controller: `Controller(model, view)` and use the View to render itself. `view.render();` View contains DOM elements that we `appendChild()`to the page. Event handlers for that element are contained in the Controller.

Comment: When the user interacts with the element, then controller gets the instance of the view or the model accordingly. `.on('click', function(e) { this.model.coords = +5;})` I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: It sounds a bit like you're describing hierarchical MVC. In basic terms, it's MVC all the way down - each MVC can contain another MVC as its view. The top level MVC will get some data, maybe transform it and pass it down, the one below might do a similar operation until you get to the final MVC component that will just display it. E.g., you might start with a DB record of a `Person` in the top level -> prune the system fields -> pass down -> prune non-relevant fields -> pass down -> get just name -> display. A sibling to the last component might instead show something like account balance.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  I haven't heard about HMVC before. Definitely gonna have to look at it and try to implement it. Thanks